# Question about Automating Long vs Short Orders

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, trading

I have been working on a pine editor script that is supposed to place a long order when the prior candle closing price (and current price) is above "Lead Line 1" and "Lead Line 2" of the Ichimoku Cloud indicator, and a short order when the prior candle closing price (and current price) is below both of the lines. Additionally, when an order is placed a stop loss should be placed either 2x the ATR above (for short positions) or below (for long positions) the entry price. This is shown visually by a trailing line above and below the candles. The take profit should be 1.5x the difference between the stop loss and entry price.

As you will see from my screen shots the long and short entries seem to be taken anywhere, and I am not too sure that the stop loss and take profit functions are working correctly either.

This picture shows a long position being taken both within the cloud and under the cloud (both of which I do not want)

[image]

This picture shows a short position being taken above the cloud, which also should not happen.

[image]

Does anyone have a solution to this problem? I will attach my code, but I will greatly appreciate any help or advice you can give.

```
//@version=4
strategy("Ichimoku Cloud, STC, CMF, and ATR Strategy", shorttitle="Strategy", overlay=true)

// Ichimoku Cloud
conversionPeriods = input(defval=20, minval=1, title="Ichimoku Conversion Line Length", group="Ichimoku Cloud")
basePeriods = input(30, minval=1, title="Ichimoku Base Line Length", group="Ichimoku Cloud")
laggingSpan2Periods = input(120, minval=1, title="Ichimoku Lagging Span 2 Length", group="Ichimoku Cloud")
displacement = input(60, minval=1, title="Ichimoku Displacement", group="Ichimoku Cloud")
donchian(len) => avg(lowest(len), highest(len))
conversionLine = donchian(conversionPeriods)
baseLine = donchian(basePeriods)
leadLine1 = avg(conversionLine, baseLine)
leadLine2 = donchian(laggingSpan2Periods)

p1 = plot(leadLine1, offset = displacement - 1, color=color.green,
     title="Lead 1")
p2 = plot(leadLine2, offset = displacement - 1, color=color.red,
     title="Lead 2")
fill(p1, p2, color = leadLine1 > leadLine2 ? color.green : color.red)

// Average True Range (ATR)
ATR = atr(input(defval=14, type=input.integer, title="ATR", group="Averge True Range (ATR)"))[1]
Multip = input(defval=2, type=input.integer, title="Multiplier", group="Averge True Range (ATR)")

// Risk to Reward Ratio (RR)
rr = input(defval=2.0, title="Risk to Reward Ratio", group="Risk to Reward Ratio")

// Stop Loss & Target Price
longStopPrice = low - ATR * Multip
longStopDistance = close - longStopPrice
longTargetPrice = close + (longStopDistance * rr)

shortStopPrice = high + ATR * Multip
shortStopDistance = close + shortStopPrice
shortTargetPrice = close - (shortStopDistance * rr)

plot(longStopPrice,"Long Stop Loss")
plot(shortStopPrice,"Short Stop Loss")

// Long vs. Short Positon
validLong = close[1] > leadLine1 and close[1] > leadLine2
validShort = close[1] < leadLine1 and close[1] < leadLine2

// Enter trades whenever a valid setup is detected
strategy.entry(id="Long", long=strategy.long, when=validLong)
strategy.entry(id="Short", long=strategy.short, when=validShort)

// Exit trades whenever our stop or target is hit
strategy.exit(id="Long Exit", from_entry="Long", limit=longTargetPrice, stop=longStopPrice, when=strategy.position_size > 0)
strategy.exit(id="Short Exit", from_entry="Short", limit=shortTargetPrice, stop=shortStopPrice, when=strategy.position_size < 0)
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to plot your Leadline with no offset. The plot and the actual data of those two lines can be confusing.

Comment: Well the plot is more for visualization anyways. The main problem is with the numbers themselves and (I think) how I have setup the variables. Also that code with the displacement and everything is how Trading View setup that indicator.

Comment: Ok nevermind, I think I see what you are saying with the displacement. The displacement is definitely messing everything up. I guess the question is how do I include the displacement within my variable...

Answer (score 0):

You have to take into account the displacement. When the leading lines are offset into the future, the current close is actually above/below a historical value of the leading lines. eg

```
validLong = close[1] > leadLine1[displacement - 1] and close[1] > leadLine2[displacement - 1]
```